# Getting and interpreting raw(byte array/pixel) image from Android 5.0 and above

Tags: java, android, image-processing, camera, android-ndk

I have done my assignment, I can't seem to find information that suits my need, but I will would like to know how I can get raw(byte array/pixel) frames from the Android Camera, and if possible in NDK, and if so, what format should I expect and how to interpret it.

Comment: A raw byte array presumably wouldn't have a format, it would be `x` rows by `y` columns of pure color goodness (could be RGB, CMYK, or anything else). Beyond that, I do not know.

Comment: That would be great, after all, i want the image to have as little conversion/processing as possible. pure color goodness.